# Flow: HTMLVideoElement and HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, casting, flowtype

I'm using Flow to typecheck my app.

I have a dom node I have to pull manually using `document.querySelector`. In Flow's eyes, this returns an `HTMLElement`. It's actually returning a video element, which I typecheck as `HTMLVideoElement`.

I'm trying to cast it, but it still errors out. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let videoElement: HTMLVideoElement;
videoElement = document.querySelector('video') // type is HTMLElement, errors out.
```

```html
<video class="lol"></video>
```

The error I get is `This type is incompatible with
HTMLVideoElement`.

Comment: What is the actual error you'd get? Flow should know it's a video, the issue is that it could also be `null`, which your type doesn't capture.

Comment: updated with the actual error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is unrelated to the fact that it is a video. If you look at [the type definition for `querySelector('video')`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/ba4482b57cfd82c7fe1a2800048c66b6caec5ca0/lib/dom.js#L773), it is

```
querySelector(selector: 'video'): HTMLVideoElement | null;
```

which if you look closely, *is* incompatible with the type you've put on your variable. `querySelector` can return `null` and you are ignoring that fact. Flow is catching a potential bug here and making you verify and handle the buggy case, which is its entire job.

So you have a few options

1. Annotate it with `null` and check when you use the variable to handle it, e.g.

   ```
   let videoElement: HTMLVideoElement | null  = document.querySelector('video');
   ```
2. Explicitly check and throw so flow can know that you *want* it to error, e.g.

   ```
   let result = document.querySelector('video');
   if (!result) throw new Error("Video not found");

   // Technically you don't need to reassign and you can reuse 
   // 'result' but I'm doing it for clarity.
   let videoElement: HTMLVideoElement = result;
   ```
3. Tell Flow you 100% sure it will always find the video by using `any`

   ```
   let videoElement: HTMLVideoElement = (document.querySelector('video'): any);
   ```
4. Explicitly tell flow to ignore errors on that line. In your `.flowconfig` do

   ```
   [options]
   suppress_comment= \\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowIgnore
   ```

   then in your code do

   ```
   let videoElement: HTMLVideoElement;

   // $FlowIgnore
   videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working by hacking around the typesystem, casting it to `any`, then recasting that to `HTMLVideoElement`.

```
      videoElement = ((document.querySelector('video'): any): HTMLVideoElement);
```